# Using Visual Studio with Google Colab

Tags: visual-studio

I have purchased a premium subscription to Google Colab and would like to integrate with Visual Studio Code IDE to run my code.

Is there any documentation to do this?

I read some internet blogs but it seems it's a third party and I got a warning not to use those in collab so I stopped.

Looking for feedback here.